# Break a loop without appending the string that stops the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to break a while loop without appending the string ("stop") and without having to enter a quantity for the stop word.

```
while True:
    try:
        product = get_user_input("Input the product name: ")
        quantity = get_user_input("Input the product quantity: ", int)
        shopping_list.add_item(product, quantity)
        if product == "stop":
            break
        else:
            continue
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nAn error occurred:", e)
```

Comment: Why not put the add line (`shopping_list.add_item(product, quantity)`) in the `else` block?

Comment: `else` isn't strictly required; `break` itself prevents any code following the `if` from executing.

Comment: Also, you may as well check the value of `product` *before* you prompt for the (possibly unnecessary) quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `product` is `"stop"`, there's no need to prompt for a quantity *or* add anything to the shopping list. Make that check *earlier*.

```
while True:
    try:
        product = get_user_input("Input the product name: ")
        if product == "stop":
            break
        quantity = get_user_input("Input the product quantity: ", int)
        shopping_list.add_item(product, quantity)
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nAn error occurred:", e)
```